# How to clear Google Drive syncing queue on macOS?

Tags: macos, google-drive-api

Google Drive Desktop uploaded over 100K files to the cloud. However, the application shows that syncing is still in progress.

[image]

Reinstallation and re-login have not reset the queue.

How to remove Google Drive syncing queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quit the app and remove its data by the following command

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/DriveFS/[0-9]*
```

More details in [the article](https://remarkablemark.medium.com/how-to-clear-google-drive-cache-abf9efc6089e)